# Bundle Display Name and plist

Tags: xcode, sdk, plist, bundle, info.plist

I am new to this, and I would like to submit my app. I am stuck on the plist. 
I have no clue what to put for bundle display name, bundle name and identifier and executable file? the name of my app is ReportsIGS.
any help in this will help me out a lot. Thank you so much.....
I am sorry if this was answered already somewhere else, i just cant seem to find it..

Comment: We're these two questions not helpful?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337639/how-do-i-change-the-display-name-in-xcode-5

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667582/bundle-name-and-bundle-display-name

Answer (score 0):

The defaults for the executable name and bundle identifier are `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` and `com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`, respectively. The `${}` means Xcode will fill in those spaces automatically, so the only part of those two fields you need to change are the `com.yourcompany.` part of the identifier. If you have a website, you should use your domain name in reverse order, so if your website is `example.com`, you would use `com.example`. If you don't have a website, you should be OK just using your company name or your name in place of `yourcompany`. The default for the bundle name is `${PRODUCT_NAME}`. This should also be good enough. The display name is the only thing you may want to change, but `${PRODUCT_NAME}` should be sufficient here too since your name isn't very long.

During the build phase, Xcode will convert the `${}` fields as follows (using your example):

> ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} -> ReportsIGS
>   ${PRODUCT_NAME} -> ReportsIGS
>   ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} -> ReportsIGS (Special characters/whitespace would be converted/removed, but you didn't use any)