# Can two application have the same Bundle Name, but different Bundle Identifier?

Tags: ios

If two apps have different Bundle Identifiers but the same title, does it mean they will store in the same place in the real device?

Comment: hopefully I salvaged this question to make it more clear what you are trying to do, @AdamLee

Comment: As the product name you can use any name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667582/bundle-name-and-bundle-display-name

Comment: if two of your apps have the same `bundle identifier`, they will be installed above each other in real device, so that need to be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle identifiers have to be unique which means you can not have two apps with the same bundle ID installed on the device. The product name does not have to be unique which makes a lot of sense because it would be difficult to avoid accidental conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since this has been posted. But thought this might be helpful to someone who's looking for information.

Bundle Identifier is something which is unique to each app. Each app on the AppStore must have a different Bundle Identifier, else you are going to face problems when you are going to submit your app to the app store.

Regarding the title of the app in the phone menu, it doesn't matter as it's just the display name of the app on the phone.

But when you are picking a name to display your app in the app store, it should be a unique one. Anyway Apple doesn't let you to have two apps with same name in the app store. If someone else is having your name you have to change your name or if you have trademark rights to the name and would like it released for your use, you will have to submit a claim.