# How do I change the display name in Xcode 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode5

I clicked on TARGET > INFO then changed BUNDLE DISPLAY NAME to what I want it to be, but when I archive it, the previous name (same as the target name) is still there.

Answer (score 24):

Change "Bundle display name" in your PLIST file.

[image: In your -Info.plist]

Comment: It's just Bundle name now.

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle Display Name` appears when you install the build on a device. To change the name of your archive, change `Bundle Name` and `Executable File` as well.