# Cannot find Bundle Display Name in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode6

If my app's product name was "AppName: Some Description", I just want "AppName" to show as a name underneath the app icon on iOS home screen. I did some searching and found this SO question ([Change name of iPhone app in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043066/change-name-of-iphone-app-in-xcode-4)). I'm using Xcode 6 and I cannot find the **Bundle Display Name** in the **Info.plist**. Can someone please tell me how to do this in Xcode 6.

Thanks

**Update:**

Simply place your cursor to the Info.plist and click on the + button. Select "Bundle display name" and insert name in the value section.

[image]

Comment: We're these two questions not helpful?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337639/how-do-i-change-the-display-name-in-xcode-5

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667582/bundle-name-and-bundle-display-name

Comment: There is no Bundle Display Name in the Info.plist in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bundle Name is what you have to set in  the info.plist to display the name on the iOS home screen

**Edit:**

you still have bundle display name in xcode 6. Just add it in the info.plist

Comment: I'm still confused. Why did they have both Bundle Display Name and Bundle Name before Xcode 6?

Comment: you still have bundle display name in xcode 6. Just add it in the info.plist

Comment: Wow. Time nicely wasted. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

To change the name appearing underneath your app icon, modify the CFBundleDisplayName key in your **Info.plist**.

1. Click the disclosure triangle next to the "Supporting Files" subfolder to reveal its content.
2. Select the Info.plist file to reveal a property list editor of keys and values.
3. By default, Xcode displays a human-readable string of a key rather than its actual name. So, search the property list for "Bundle display name". Skip to step 5 if your property list already shows Bundle display name.

> If it doesn't, add it to your list as follows:
>
> ```
>   - Click on any entry in your list, then click the "+" button.
>   - Choose Bundle display name from the ensuing pop-up menu.
> ```

4. Double-click in the Value column of Bundle display name.
5. Enter a new value for Bundle display name as shown in Figure

[image]

[Technical Q&A QA1823](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html)